# php шаблон, как сделать рендер?

Tags: php

Просьба помочь разобраться с простеньким рендером шаблона.
Для удобства весь код разместил в одном файле

```
echo tpl(rootdir.'/tpl/text/text.inc', array('url' => 'yandex'));

function tpl($file, $params = false)
{
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    $inc = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    foreach($params as $label => $value)
    {
        $inc = preg_replace("/\{".$label."\}/uis", $value, $inc);
    }

    return $inc;
} 

function replacer($url)
{
    $url = preg_replace("/yandex/uis", "google", $url);
    return $url;
}
```

в самом шаблоне `text.inc` находится следующий код

```
echo replacer("{url}");
```

По задумке после того как заинклудился файл шаблона, я думал заменить в нем `{url}` на свое значение, стартануть функцию `replacer` с подставленным значением, произвести замену и вернуть результат в `echo tpl`. Как вы понимаете, ничего такого не произошло - `replacer` не отрабатывает. Причем указав ручками ему параметр вместо `{url}` - все ок.
Я понимаю, что как-то надо рендер сделать, но что-то растерялся - не пойму куда копать и как копать!

Comment: _для удобства_ надо было взять twig или smarty

Comment: нет, я не хочу ничего брать, я хочу сам сделать.

Comment: вывод текста с плейсхолдерами,  очистка буфера, и замена их регулярками это провальный путь шаблонизации. передавайте данные сразу в шаблон, зачем ва этим плейсхолдеры нужны вообще? костыль какой-то.

Comment: ну с `extract` все нормально будет, да, меня чисто технически заинтересовал способ подмены плейсхолдера. может действительно, вернуться к `extract`, я с него собственно и начал, чисто технически потом уже заморочился регулярками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант заработает после замены include на require.
При этом надо не забыть использовать `<?php`, иначе, ваш шаблон будет восприниматься как текст, а не код.

Вариант, который мне кажется лучше (чистый PHP).
Шаблон:

```
<div><?=replacer($url)?></div>
```

Код:

```
function replacer($url) 
{
    return str_replace('yandex', 'google', $url);
}

function phptpl($fileName, $params) {
    extract($params);
    ob_start();
    require($fileName);
    return ob_get_clean();
}

echo phptpl('tpl.php', ['url' => 'yandex']); // <div>google</div>
```

Comment: да, с переменными и extract все работает, меня заинтересовал метод подмены плейсхолдера - что с ним не так :) ваш вариант да, работает, я с него и начинал :) спасибо за ответ!